# Store and Fetch data from SqliteDataBase

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating an app in which I want to show all users list in `RecyclerView`. And the users list data coming from server. I have successfully added 
data in `RecyclerView` and working perfectly but now I want to store all data in `SqliteDatabase` and on no network connection I want to fetch data from `sqlite` and show in `RecyclerView` means I want to show all list in offline mode also(same as coming from server).
I have created database but I don't know where is the error, I am not getting all data. How to do this?

**Here is my SqliteDataBase:**

```
public long insertContact(int userId, String name, String profile, String status) {
    long result = 0;
    open();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("USERID", userId);
    contentValues.put("NAME", name);
    contentValues.put("PROFILE", profile);
    contentValues.put("STATUS", status);
    result = sqLiteDataBase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_CONTACT, null, contentValues);
    return result;
}

public Cursor getallEntry() {
    return sqLiteDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_CONTACT, null, null, null, "ID", null, "ID");
}
```

**Here I am calling insertContact in class, ContactList contains data coming from server:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
    sqliteDataBase.insertContact(contactList.get(i).getId(),
            contactList.get(i).getName(),"",status);
```

**Here I am fetching all data when no network connection:**

```
if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        getAllUserList();
    }
    else {
        Cursor cursor = sqliteDataBase.getallEntry();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this method in your Database class

```
 public void insertContact(ContentValues values) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = _dbWriteable;
        db.insert(Your.TABLENAME, null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and in your activity, where you get the server response, insert the values in db like this.

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    Database db = new Database(mContext);
    for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
        contentValues.put("USERID", userId);
        contentValues.put("NAME", name);
        contentValues.put("PROFILE", profile);
        contentValues.put("STATUS", status);
        db.insertContact(values);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to get all records

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```